# Как распарсить из HTML непечатаемые спец.символы

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

На сайте с попощью javascript после клика на элемент формируется HTML-таблица, и в одной из ячеек таблицы выводятся данные вида:

```
Город (1), улица (1), 1,4,6,7,9,12,15,16
Город (2), улица (2), 15,16,19,22,23,24,25,26
Город (3), улица (3),             // имеется ввиду вся улица
Город (4), улица (4), 1,2,4,7,9,12,12б,12в
...
Город (n), улица (n), 23,27,28,45,49,52,55,56
```

Вместо город (n) и улица (n) свои уникауальные названия.

На Java c помощью selenium webdriver и phantomJS произвожу парсинг этих данных:

```
public class Parser {
    public void getHTML() {
        DesiredCapabilities settings = new DesiredCapabilities();
        settings.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService
                .PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,"C:\\BrowserDriver\\phantomjs\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(settings);
        driver.get("http://website.com/");
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[2]/td[5]/h5");
        System.out.println(element.getText());
    }
}
```

Код работает, ячейка парсится. Но проблема в том, что в ячейке теряются непечатаемые знаки типа знака перевода на новую строку \n или знака обзаца \u2029. 
Если открыть в инструментах разработчика Chrome эту ячейку, то текст будет представлен отформатированным с этими непечатаемыми знаками, а отображается на странице и после выполнения моего кода уже без этих знаков, т.е. всё в одну строку. Т.е., наверно, могу сделать правильный вывод, что эти знаки в коде страницы всё-таки присутствуют.
Мне нужно "распарсить" эту ячейку на топонимы в структуру, типа:

```
String city;
String street;
List<String> buildings;
```

Со знаками абзаца идет разделение на строки и разобрать строки будет не трудно: до первой запятой это город, между первой и второй запятой это улица, остальное это номера домов. А когда всё в одну строку выводится, то алгоритм разбора гораздо усложняется.

Полагаю, что webdriver (какой-то из методов) "чистит" эти знаки.
В общем вопрос: как распарсить эти данные не теряя непечатаемые знаки?

Answer (score 0):

Эти элементы чистит не Селениум. Он передаёт то, что ему передал браузер. Если мне не изменяет память, это делает PhantomJS и Chrome, но я могу ошибаться. Что вам нужно сделать. Есть два варианта.

1. Передать HTML код страницы целиком, стороннему парсеру (я не разбираюсь в Java библиотеках, но к примеру в Python 3 есть `lxml` (которой я пользуюсь) и `Beautiful Soup`). И уже этой библиотекой достать информацию (она должна быть "сырой", то есть все эти символы будут в строковом виде `"Привет\n"`). Пример кода на Python 3:

```
from lxml import html                        # импорт библиотеки парсинга

driver.get(url)                              # идём на страницу
html_code = driver.page_source               # сохраняем HTML страницы в "html_code" 
tree = html.fromstring(html_code)            # отдаём данные HTML парсеру
element = tree.xpath(element_xpath_address)  # ищем в них элемент по xPath
print(element)                               # выводим найденный элемент(ы)
```

2. Или попробуй другой браузер, альтернатив не много, предлагаю Firefox)))))) Я не уверен на 100%, но по моему, в том числе и из-за данного различия я и перешёл на Firefox.